# Tableview Pagination not working in swift

Tags: json, swift, pagination, tableview

I have added tableview bottom pagination with json data

json response in postman:

```
"result": {
"page_count": 3,
"per_page": 10,
"post_count": 27,
"Payments": [
  {
    "id": 132,
    "payment_response": null,
```

**code:** *if i run this code then without scrolling the paymentsServiceCall() calling 4 times but table data showing only first 10 records*, why? where am i wrong.

i need initially 10 cells to show on tableview then if i scroll then 10 more cells to load and so on. please guide me

```
class MyPaymentsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
private var currentPage = 1
private var totalPages = 1

private var paymentsData = PaymentsHistoryModel(dictionary: NSDictionary()) {
    didSet {
        totalPages = paymentsData?.result?.page_count ?? 0
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    currentPage = 1
    paymentsServiceCall()
}
func paymentsServiceCall() {
    let param = ["page_no": currentPage]
    
    serviceCall(param: param, method: .post, url: CommonUrl.student_my_payments) { [weak self] (resp) in
        if let _ = resp.dict?["result"] as? NSDictionary {
            self?.paymentsData = PaymentsHistoryModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
        }
    }
}
}

extension MyPaymentsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let totalPostCount = paymentsData?.result?.payments?.count
        if indexPath.row == totalPostCount - 1, currentPage <= totalPages {
            print("in refresh")
            currentPage += 1
            paymentsServiceCall()
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    paymentsData?.result?.payments?.count ?? 0
}
}
```

Comment: This question needs more debugging details. Set breakpoints to determine what function gets called at what time. Come back to us with the details.

Comment: @burnsi, initially breakpoint hits inside `paymentsServiceCall > self?.paymentsData = PaymentsHistoryModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())`
then tableview reloads
then goes to same time `willDisplay` and `currentPage` increased by 1 and same like 3 times

Comment: but in tableview data shows only first 10 records

Comment: @burnsi without scrolling breakpoint goes to `willDisplay` and currentPage count increasing

Comment: I would guess you need a different approach to determine when to load new data. As it seems `willDisplay`  will be called each time you refresh the tableView.

Comment: @burnsi, yeahh, please share the code snippet for pagination with json data

Comment: Come to think of it, the issue seems related to the way you set your data with `self?.paymentsData = PaymentsHistoryModel(...`. You are replacing the datasource each time you load new data. Instead you need a way to append the data to it. But there is a lot unknown here, so I cannot compile an answer to this.

Comment: Who knows? :) I think the best way would be to try to solve this on your own. I gave you a direction on how to. If you get stuck update your question with the appropriate information and give me a bump.

Comment: You need to append new data in paymentsData. Right now your code is replacing existing paymentsData

Comment: @HabinLama, you mean need to take one more `payments` type array, and append `paymentsData?.result?.payments` to paymentsArray?

Comment: @HabinLama, can you show the sample code snippet

Answer (score 1):

**Try Using This**

```
class PaginationManager {
    var isLoading = false
    static let shared = PaginationManager()
    private init() {   } //Singleton
    
}
extension PaginationManager {
    
    func isPaging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        let bounds = scrollView.bounds
        let size = scrollView.contentSize
        let inset = scrollView.contentInset
        let y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom
        let h = size.height

        let reload_distance: CGFloat = 100.0
        if y > h - reload_distance && !isLoading {
            return true
        }
        return false

    }
    
    func isPagingForTopScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        _ = scrollView.bounds
        let size = scrollView.contentSize
        _ = scrollView.contentInset
        let y = offset.y
        _ = size.height

        let reload_distance: CGFloat = 100.0
        if y < reload_distance && !isLoading {
            return true
        }
        return false

    }

}
```

**And for using it in Controller**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if PaginationManager.shared.isPaging(scrollView) {
            if !(paymentsData?.result?.payments?.isEmpty ?? true), totalPages > paymentsData?.result?.payments?.count ?? 0 {
                guard PaginationManager.shared.isLoading else { return }
                track("######Loading: \(viewModel.isLoading)")
                //Call your service to fetch new data with an updated page number below
            }
        }
    }
```

**After calling the service again check for appending the data in payments or if it is the first page then replace it with new data and inside the service response update the current page count by 1**

You can also create isLoading var in your class if multiple service calls are there.